# machine learning model vs time series model?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

A general question about machine learning models vs classical time series model in prediction tasks? When to use machine learning models, when to use time series models? What is the advantage and disadvantage of them?

My first thought is time series models are more widely used when there is 1 predictor. However, there are multivariate time series models so this argument doesn't really stand.

Another thought is about the assumption of the model. For example, many machine learning model assumes independence of data while time series model does not. But what else? when should we use machine learning models for prediction task instead of time series models?

Comment: Re <<many machine learning model assumes independence of data>> that's not quite accurate, it is always possible to apply [PCA and reduce the dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction)/dependencies. Generally, apply anything that works, gives a better [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score), doesn't boil the planet or contribute substantially to the CO2 emotion (e.g. is not expensive in terms of hardware and energy consumption) and gives you an answer within an acceptable time frame.

Comment: Also, you may occasionally need both ML and Time series combined. Learn as may techniques as you can ... and more. To give you an example, I was trying to build a good clustering (unsupervised ML) algorithm for IP addresses for some time. Many existing techniques wasn't working ... until one day I "rediscovered" [Hilbert Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve). After a short demo, the data science team at Wandera (I used to work for them) [made a product from it](https://medium.com/wandera-engineering/how-we-mapped-the-internet-to-discover-carriers-ba9a9ad586e5).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this paper on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04110). It expounds on the following:

> We demonstrate how by applying deep learning techniques to forecasting, one can overcome many of the challenges faced by widely-used classical approaches to the problem.

I think you're right in terms of the one or several time series being predicted: at least Amazon Web Services [claims the following](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/aws-forecast-recipe-deeparplus.html) for the above arXiv-presented model:

> When your dataset contains hundreds of feature time series, the DeepAR+ algorithm outperforms the standard ARIMA and ETS methods

I hope that this gives you some (at least close to) cutting edge work done on machine learning for time series. After all, if "classical" time series models e.g. ARIMA didn't have room for improvement, there would be no comparison to make!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem in the past. Here are some ideas about this.

1. If you have not many datapoints (for instance less than a hundred), classical models are your natural solution. In this cases neural nets can have a lot of over-fitting and may be problematic.
2. If your data has a clear seasonal component, you may want to go with a trend-seasonal decomposition, which is based on Fourier analysis and exploits the periodic behavior of the data better than deep learning in my opinion.
3. If you need to have a clear interpretation of the data rather than only a forecasting model, you may want to use classical approaches since deep learning is sometimes *black box*.
4. In the case that simple, and classical explanations for the data fail or high complexity (multiple variables, irregularity...), deep learning will give you more precise models.

In general I would recommend to use classical and simple models as initial approximations and then use deep learning tools to try to improve them in terms of forecasting of classification error.

I strongly recommend this course and book by Aileen Nielsen in which she discuses precisely this topic among others:

- Practical Time Series Analysis by Aileen Nielsen
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNfxr4BQrLk&t=6204s